# MapView leaves polylines on screen after removal

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm having some trouble with MKPolylines. Basically: I have a big thick purple (less detailed) polyline for a route overview, and a thin red (accurate) one for "focus" on a route. They, for the most part, are the same, but the red one follows corners more accurately, etc.

My problem is this: I start at the overview, then go into focus - replacing one of the purple polylines with a red one - and then go back to overview, which puts the purple one back, and then **delete the route**, which gets rid of the polyline altogether. When I follow this sequence of steps, part of the **red** polyline is left behind, until I zoom in or out, which refreshes the map tile. Note: once part of the purple polyline was left behind, but I haven't been able to reproduce that.

This seems like it must be a bug in MapKit, but I can't figure out a workaround for the time being. Has anyone else found this before? Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Why not call

```
[mapView setNeedsDisplay];
```

or

```
[myPolyLineView setNeedsDisplay];
```

after removing it?